# "unmute-audio" callback of Web RTC is not triggering

Tags: agora.io

I am using RTC for Web. "unmute-audio" callback is not triggering when remote user click on unmute button in mobile app.But it will trigger "stream-added" callback. In mobile I am using below function for mute and unmute stream.[Used function for mute and unmute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1UTD.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 client.on("stream-subscribed", function(evt){
  var stream = evt.stream;
  // Mutes the remote stream.
  stream.unmuteAudio();
});
```

try this

Comment: I used above code it is working properly. But "unmute-audio" callback needs to be work becaus I am updating UI according that. "unmute-audio" will provide userId of remote user who unmuted audio.

Comment: please explain it in detail

Comment: We created one mobile app by integrating agora RTC (only Voice) . So I am creating web app for that. There are two callbacks available in Web RTC 1) "unmute-audio" 2) "mute-audio". So "unmute-audio" callback needs to be trigger when user clicks on unmute button in mobile app. In mobile app for unmute and mute button I used muteLocalAudioStream(). you can find method description here https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/flutter/rtc_engine/RtcEngine/muteLocalAudioStream.html.

Answer (score 0):

"unmute-audio" callback will give userID of remote user who unmuted himself.
As I mentioned in quetion "stream-added" is triggering instead of "unmute-audio". So it is possible to get same userId from "stream-added" callback also. So now I can update mute and unmute status in UI.